# Handle a PHP error message when a second node doesn't exist?

Tags: php, error-handling, undefined

Hope someone can help with this

I'm using this to grab the first part of my `URL`

```
$page_url = perch_page_url(['include-domain' => false,], true); // 
Output the URL of the current page, minus https
$url_parts = explode("/", $page_url); // Split a string by a string
```

I'm using this technique to grab the first and second nodes of the `URL`

```
$first_node = $url_parts[1]; // First part of string 
$second_node = $url_parts[2]; // Second part of string
```

On my homepage, there isn't a second node, so I get an `undefined offset` message.

Is there a way to check if the `$second_node` exists?

I've tried using

```
if (isset($second_node)) {
echo "$second_node is set so I will print.";
}
```

and

```
if (!empty($second_node)) {
echo '$second_node is either 0, empty, or not set at all';  
}
```

Both `if` statements only echo after the $second_node has been set? So I still get the error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$second_node = isset($url_parts[2]) ? $url_parts[2] : FALSE;
if ($second_node)
{
    echo "Second node: {$second_node}";
}
```

This checks if the third index (0-based) of the `$url_parts` array is set. If yes, it will assign its value to `$second_node`. If not, it will assign `FALSE` so you can handle that further down in the code if you need to check it later (again).

Comment: This is great, it does exactly what I needed. Thanks Mario.

Comment: How would I use your example with this: `$post_title = perch_blog_post_field(perch_get('s'), 'postTitle', true);`

Comment: @StephenMeehan I think this is a different question. My example checks if a particular array entry exists. But your example does not use any array. If you want to check if `$post_title` contains anything you can use either `empty($post_title)` or `strlen($post_title)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use it directly in the if condition and avoid assigning to a variable or assign after checking it in if condition

```
if (isset($url_parts[2])) { // remove this line $second_node = $url_parts[2]; 
echo "$second_node is set so I will print.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I can use this in another part of my website. However, for this particular issue I needed to assign the variable in one location and test for it's existence.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the error is thrown at the initialization of your `$second_node` variable.

Check if the node exists first, and then declare the variable:

```
$second_node = ""; // Or whatever
if (isset($url_parts[2]) {
    $second_node = $url_parts[2];
}
```

Check it here: https://3v4l.org/fRJ7L

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. So I can set the variable, but give it no value. Nice. Also, didn't know about that tool you linked to. Appreciated.